# How to stack data from multiple sources in grafana

Tags: influxdb, grafana

We're trying to stack data from multiple sources using Grafana. Currently we use 1 query for all of the data (`SELECT value FROM source1, source2, source3, ...`) but when enabling '`stack`' on '`multiple series`', it shows the wrong values (blue shows the value for blue + yellow).
I can't get the graph to work when using multiple queries (if we use multiple queries, it only shows us the first one, never both at the same time).

Any clue on how to get this working? The end result should look like the image but the values should display correctly. If yellow is 10 and blue is 10, they should both show 10, instead of yellow showing 10 and blue showing 20.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must select "individual" instead "cumulative" in "Stacked Values" ("Display Styles" tab) to keep original values instead sum of previous values.

[image: Individual values]
[image: Result example]